# How to concat additional string with the typescript type definition object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

Let says I have a type as follows:

```
export enum configType {
  value = 'blah bala',
  value2 = 'blah bala',
  value3 = 'blah bala',
  value2 = 'blah bala',

}
```

Now I want to create a new type with above enum as follows:

```
export type analog = {
    [v + '_key' in configType]?: boolean;
}
```

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) the type utilities [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) and [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9iAZgSwOYBUCeAHYUDeAUFFAGoCGANmHgLxQDkF1wDANMWVTQExT1NuwHu07MaAZn6NxwCaJKyALNMEslogL6FCAFxx4AgiCpxU0gArkATruRUAPACVgAYzjWAJg4AGAEnx4JDQsXE0AfQBrYEwfNigAIzg4SmByEAA+DIBuHQB6ACodfVwoY1NzeiJFISiYgH4ALkTk1PTcmpYeOswmlpS0kA6uFgkevqSB9rEhJXHmybahwm1CArygA)

```ts
enum ConfigType {
  Value = 'Value',
  Value2 = 'Value2',
  Value3 = 'Value3',
  Value4 = 'Value4',
}

type Analog = Partial<Record<`${ConfigType}_key`, boolean>>;

/*

type Analog = {
  Value_key?: boolean;
  Value2_key?: boolean;
  Value3_key?: boolean;
  Value4_key?: boolean;
}

*/
```

Comment: Can we also change the key-value type along with this? because currently key value is converted to any, but I need it as string.

Comment: @FRSTAR If you have a new question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).